# Se puede transformar un formato de fecha y hora a segundos desde la epoca en Python?

Tags: python, date

estaba armando un script en python y quería saber si es posible convertir de formato de fecha y hora a segundos desde la época, es decir transformar de 2020/06/01 19:12:00 a 1591038720 segundos

¿Que estructura necesitaría armar o si esto ya esta incluido en una librería cual sería?, agradecería su pronta ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Convertir la cadena a datetime

Para ello simplemente usa el método `datetime.datetime.strptime`, teniendo en cuenta el formato de tu fecha para construir la cadena especificadora de formato de acuerdo a  [strftime and strptime format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

### Obtener tiempo desde época

Una vez que tengas tu objeto `datetime` basta con usar el método [`timestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) de dicho objeto.

---

```
from datetime import datetime

time_epoc = datetime.strptime(
    "2020/06/01 19:12:00", "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"
    ).timestamp()
```

> ```
> >>> time_epoc
> 1591031520.0
> ```

Otra opción si vas a trabajar mucho con fechas y especialmente con zonas horarias es usar [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import arrow


time_epoc = arrow.get("2020/06/01 19:12:00").timestamp
```

es más completo y sobretodo "amable para humanos" que `datetime`.

Comment: Muchas gracias por las 2 opciones, ahora las probare para quedarme con la que mas me funcione

Answer (score 0):

```
  from datetime import datetime

  import time

  dt = datetime.strptime('2020/06/01 19:12:00', '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

  ts = time.mktime(dt.timetuple())

  ts
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda lo que me estaba faltando era el definir en que formato los estaba introduciendo

Comment: Una explicación del código siempre se agradece, checa [answer]